# regex not working properly with $in operator

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongoose and nodejs. I am trying to query an array field of mongoose schema using regular expression but I am getting an empty array even if there are matching elements. This is how my code looks like:

```
var regex = { $regex: new RegExp(req.query.query, 'i')};

var query = {$or: [
  {name: regex}
  , {ditributionAreas: {$in: [regex]}}
 ]};

TiffinboxSupplier.find(query, function(err, tiffinBoxSuppliers) {

  if(err) { return next(err); };
  res.json(tiffinBoxSuppliers);
});
```

Code works fine for `name` field but giving issues with `distributionAreas` array. Am I doing some mistake with `$in` operator? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `$or` instead to cover all regex. `$in` won't work.

Comment: Not really clear on what you actually want from lack of a data sample. but the comment from @SushantGupta pretty much sums up what you need to do.

Comment: @Sushant Gupta: `distributionAreas` is an array and I need to query elements in the array that matches regex. I'll be needing `$in` for comparing elements of array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to working, I only had to pass

`new RegExp(req.query.query, 'i')`

as value to `$in` operator instead of

`{ $regex: new RegExp(req.query.query, 'i')}`.

Therefore, above code becomes

```
var regex = { $regex: new RegExp(req.query.query, 'i')};

var query = {$or: [
  {name: regex}
  , {ditributionAreas: {$in: [new RegExp(req.query.query, 'i')]}}
 ]};
```

Comment: Cool, didn't knew `$in` would work on regex as well, I thought it needs to be some absolute value. Have you tested it? If it works then thanks for enlightening :)

Comment: yes I have. Posted as an answer after testing. I knew `$in` works with regex, problem was in syntax.

Comment: +1 Thanks :) I should have tested before commenting, I went with my intuition. Sorry and thanks again :)

Comment: Since there is only **one** element in the `$in` statement then you do not actually need it. You don't have to use `$in` just because you have an array `{distributionAreas: regex }` is exactly the same thing in this case.